# Hot to load a single object in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

There the such example in angular docs to load an array:

```
   var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
   var user = User.get({userId:123}, function() {
   user.abc = true;
   user.$save();
  });
```

But how to write code to reload a single object

Answer (score 0):

The above does load a single object. In standard `$resource` (you can override it), the following returns an object:

```
user = User.get({userId:123}, function(ret) {
   // user is now a single object, identical to ret above
   user.abc = true;
   user.$save();
});
```

while the following returns an array of objects (could be 0, 1 or more in the array):

```
users = User.query({userId:123}, function(ret) {
   // user is now an array of objects, identical to ret above
   users.length; // in this case, probably just one
   user = users[0];
});
```

This is configured when you set up the resource, using `isArray`. See the reference here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

If you scroll down to "Returns", you will see that `query` has `isArray:true`. You can override any of that when you set up the `$resource()`

Comment: Thanks, but what it is 'ret'

Comment: `ret` is the argument to the callback function, it is the returned value of the `query()` or `get()`. It is also identical to what `user` (in the first example) or `users` (in the second example) is set to when the `get()` or `query()` is complete.